# Undefined object result from GraphQL api call - Web console shows JSON response received

Tags: json, reactjs, api, graphql

I'm using React to create a web application. I have a DynamoDB table in AWS and an AppSync API configured.

I'm using the following to make an api call:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const apiGroups = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getNtig, { PK: "Status", SK: "Active" }));
      setItems(apiGroups.data.getNtig.Group);
    })();
  }, []);
```

Later on I use the results to create a dropdown. I had this working perfectly with Rest but I'm trying to switch to using GraphQL.

I see the JSON response in the webconsole:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getNTIG": {
            "PK": "Status",
            "SK": "Active",
            "Group": [
                "Group1",
                "Group2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I always get `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): apiGroups.data.getNtig is undefined`

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, try to console.log(apiGroups) before setItems,  and look what you are getting

Comment: This is what I see in the console:{…}
​
data: {…}
​​
getNTIG: {…}
​​​
Group: (2) […]
​​​​
0: "Group1"
​​​​
1: "Group2"
​​​​
length: 2
​​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​​
PK: "Status"
​​​
SK: "Active"

Comment: OK, try const {Group} = apiGroups.data.getNtig; setItems(Group). 
Make sure you are receiving them in json format and not string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the key you are referring to is named `getNTIG` and not `getNtig`. The language is case sensitive so it is important to use the right case.

Comment: You are right! I don't see that. But in that case 
he shouldn't get the error unless data is null or undefined

Comment: Well `data` itself is defined but the key `getNtig` is not, then the error is `apiGroups.data.getNtig is undefined` and not `apiGroups.data is undefined`.

Comment: unbelieveable. Thank you for the fresh pair of eyes.